# model.evaluate() varies wildly with number of steps when using generators

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Running tensorflow 2.x in Colab with its internal keras version (tf.keras). My model is a 3D convolutional UNET for multiclass segmentation (not sure if it's relevant).
 I've successfully trained (high enough accuracy on validation) this model the traditional way but I'd like to do augmentation to improve it, therefore I'm switching to (hand-written) generators.  When I use generators I see my loss increasing and my accuracy decreasing *a lot* (e.g.: loss increasing 4-fold, not some %) in the fit.

To try to localize the issue I've tried loading my trained weights and computing the metrics on the data returned by the generators. And what's happening makes no sense. I can see that the results visually are ok.

```
model.evaluate(validationGenerator,steps=1)
2s 2s/step - loss: 0.4037 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8716

model.evaluate(validationGenerator,steps=2)
2s/step - loss: 1.7825 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7158

model.evaluate(validationGenerator,steps=4)
7s 2s/step - loss: 1.7478 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7038
```

Why would the loss vary with the number of steps? I could guess some % due to statistical variations... not 4 fold increase!

If I try

```
x,y = next(validationGenerator)
nSamples = x.shape[0]
meanLoss = np.zeros(nSamples)
meanAcc = np.zeros(nSamples)
for pIdx in range(nSamples):
  y_pred = model.predict(np.expand_dims(x[pIdx,:,:,:,:],axis=0))
  meanAcc[pIdx]=np.mean(tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(np.expand_dims(y[pIdx,:,:,:,:],axis=0),y_pred))
  meanLoss[pIdx]=np.mean(tf.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy(np.expand_dims(y[pIdx,:,:,:,:],axis=0),y_pred))
print(np.mean(meanAcc))
print(np.mean(meanLoss))
```

I get accuracy~85% and loss ~0.44. Which is what I expect from the previous fit, and it varies by vary little from one batch to the other. And these are the same exact numbers that I get if I do model.evaluate() with 1 step (using the same generator function).
However I need about 30 steps to run trough my whole training dataset. What should I do?
If I fit my already good model to this generator it indeed worsen the performances a lot (it goes from a nice segmentation of the image to uniform predictions of 25% for each of the 4 classes!!!!)

Any idea on where to debud the issue? I've also visually looked at the images produced by the generator and at the model predictions and everything looks correct (as testified by the numbers I found when evaluating using a single step). I've tried writing a minimal working example with a 2 layers model but... in it the issue does not happen.

**UPDATE: Generators code**
So, as I've been asked, these are the generators code. They're handwritten

```
def dataGen (X,Y_train):
    patchS = 64 #set the size of the patch I extract
    batchS = 16 #number of samples per batch
    nSamples = X.shape[0] #get total number of samples
    immSize = X.shape[1:] #get the shape of the iamge to crop
    #Get 4 patches from each image
    #extract them randomly, and in random patient order
    patList = np.array(range(0,nSamples),dtype='int16')
    patList = patList.reshape(nSamples,1)
    patList = np.tile(patList,(4,2))
    patList[:nSamples,0]=0 #Use this index to tell the code where to get the patch from
    patList[nSamples:2*nSamples,0]=1
    patList[2*nSamples:3*nSamples,0]=2
    patList[3*nSamples:4*nSamples,0]=3
    np.random.shuffle(patList)
    patStart=0
    Xout = np.zeros((batchS,patchS,patchS,patchS,immSize[3])) #allocate output vector   
    while True:
     Yout = np.zeros((batchS,patchS,patchS,patchS)) #allocate vector of labels
     for patIdx in range(batchS): 
       XSR = 32* (patList[patStart+patIdx,0]//2) #get the index of where to extract the patch
       YSR = 32* (patList[patStart+patIdx,0]%2)
       xStart = random.randrange(XSR,XSR+32) #get a patch randomly somewhere between a range
       yStart = random.randrange(YSR,YSR+32) 
       zStart = random.randrange(0,26)  
       patInd = patList[patStart+patIdx,1]
       Xout[patIdx,:,:,:,:] = X[patInd,xStart:(xStart+patchS),yStart:(yStart+patchS),zStart:(zStart+patchS),:]
       Yout[patIdx,:,:,:] = Y_train[patInd,xStart:(xStart+patchS),yStart:(yStart+patchS),zStart:(zStart+patchS)]
       if((patStart+patIdx)>(patList.shape[0]-2)):
         np.random.shuffle(patList) #after going through the whole list restart
         patStart=0
     patStart = patStart+batchS 
     Yout = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical (Yout, num_classes=4, dtype='float32') #convert to one hot encoding
     yield Xout, Yout
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Check your data augmentation pipeline and methods and post it here as it might be the issue

Comment: @SzymonMaszke , what should I post? The whole program is pretty large and it requires its large dataset. Is the code of the generator alone sufficient? They're really simple at the moment. Also, when I check their output it looks ok

Comment: Yes, generator would be fine (are you using `tf.data`? It would help in debugging, code readability and may save you some errors on this part) as, if I understand correctly, it's the only part that changed between the version providing expected results and this one. Additionally, you could give an overview of those operations as bullet points (for example: `random cropping` and so on ). Also, what is your batch size? Loss varies as more samples are coming through it starts to go towards real mean (maybe around `1.7` in your case). It should vary more because of augmentation as well

Comment: I've added the generators code @SzymonMaszke . As you can see they're handwritten and they don't use premade functions (it's too hard to adapt them to what I need). For now they divide the image in 4 patches (up left, down right, etc...) and they take all 4 of them, in random order and cropping in a random range. My batch size is 16. But if I do evaluate on a single batch the number I get are correct, and they fluctuate very little from one batch to another (i.e.: loss 0.44, 0.438, 0.441, compared to loss 1.7 if computed on 2 batches evaluate(gen,steps=2)

Comment: I think you are cropping exactly same parts from both `image` and `mask` though I'm not sure looking at your implementation. Make sure image corresponds to its respective mask and each pixel agrees. There is no need really to crop into `4` parts, you can just random crop both image and mask during each pass and it should work even better. For that you may check [albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) and [RandomCrop](https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/augmentations.html#albumentations.augmentations.transforms.RandomCrop) and use with `tf.data`.

Comment: The cropping is fine, I've checked it by showing the images. If I do `x,y = next(valGen)  model.evaluate(x,y)` indeed I get 85% accuracy. If I compute the accuracy myself aftern doing `x,y = next(valGen)  model.predict(x)` I get 85% accuracy. If I do  `model.evaluate(valGen,steps=1)` still 85% accuracy. It's only when I do  `model.evaluate(valGen,steps=2)` that the loss triples and accuracy drops!

Comment: So I think you really should rewrite your data augmentation towards more standard format so it's easier to debug and reason about.

Comment: What do you mean by "more standard"? Anyway, I've copy-pasted my code as is in a keras.utils.sequence class and... now it works wonderfully. God knows what happens when a normal generator is called that way... Is there a way to get more documentation for keras?

Comment: Reading their source code I guess, documentation isn't really in-depth in my opinion. By "more standard" I mean aforementioned `tf.data` with `.map` transformations and doing them by already provided libraries not by hand which is highly error prone. Anyway, if you solved this issue please add your solution as an answer for others to possibly benefit from it in the future, thanks (even better if you find the reason).

Comment: I'll add my answer, which however is a workaround and it does not explain the issue in the original code. Concerning "standard ways to do things"... Maybe you're right... But you (they?) need to realize how extremely more complex is to find out how things work and how to adapt them to one specific input format than just writing down 10 lines of basic code...

Answer (score 2):

Posting the **workaround** I've found for the future person coming here from google.

*Apparently* the issue lies in how keras calls a handwritten generator. When it was called multiple times in a row by using evaluate(gen, steps=N) apparently it returned wrong outputs. There's no documentation around about how to address this or how a generator should be written.

I ended up writing my code using a tf.keras.utils.sequence class and the same previous code now works perfectly. No way to know why.

Answer (score -1):

Here are different factors that affect loss & accuracy:

**For Accuracy**, we know that it measures the accuracy of the prediction:  i.e. correct-classes /total-classes.
While **loss** tracks the inverse-confidence of the prediction. 
A high Loss indicates that although the model is performing well with the prediction,  It is becoming uncertain of the prediction it is making.

For example, For an image classification scenario, The image of a cat is passed into two models. Model A predicts **{cat: 0.8, dog: 0.2}** and model B predicts **{cat: 0.6, dog: 0.4}**. 
Both models will score the same accuracy, but **model B** will have a **higher loss**.

On your evaluation part,  **Based on the documentation**

```
Steps: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring the evaluation round finished. Ignored with the default value of None. If x is a tf.data dataset and steps is None, 'evaluate' will run until the dataset is exhausted. This argument is not supported by array inputs.
```

So for simplify, it's getting the Nth batch of your validation samples.

It could be that the model prediction is becoming **uncertain** since the majority of the unknown data falls on those specific steps. which in your case, steps 2 & 3.
So, As the evaluation steps progress, The prediction becomes more uncertain leading to a **higher loss**.

You might need to retrain your model with more training samples but of course, you need to be careful since you might encounter overfitting.

In terms of data augmentation, you might wanna check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation) 
In Training Perspective, proper data augmentation is one of the factors that leads to good model performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is not relevant to my problem. My model was very accurate to begin with. My problem was, evidently, in what happens when multiple steps in a row are called from a hand-written generator.